# angular2 (angular2-seed) using paths in imports avoiding ../../

Tags: angular

*I'm using angular2-seed: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed*

How to create a variable to use imports absolute link instead of relative, like this:

```
import { MyService } from '@shared/services/MyService';
```

instead of:

```
import { MyService } from '../shared/services/MyService';
```

to avoid relative import paths ../../...

An example of this is the @angular import:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

How is it defined? Can we do something like this for our shared folder?

Comment: you'd have to expose your modules using .d.ts files.

Answer (score 0):

@angular is the name of folder in your script libraries folder, nothing special with `@` character.

I could guess, In order to import module as you want you should define it as module in your systemjs.config.js.

An example of systemjs.config.js currently I am using is:

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    map: {
        'app': 'app',
        'rxjs': 'libraries/rxjs',
        '@angular': 'libraries/@angular',
        'ng2-bootstrap': 'libraries/ng2-bootstrap/',
        'ng2-select': 'libraries/ng2-select',
        'moment': 'libraries/moment/moment.js'
    },
    packages: {
        'app': { main: 'main.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts'},
        'rxjs': { main: 'Rx.js' },
        '@angular/core': { main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/compiler': { main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/router': { main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/platform-browser': { main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': { main: 'index.js' },
        '@angular/http': { main: 'index.js' },
        'ng2-bootstrap': { 'defaultExtension': 'js' },
        'ng2-select': { main: 'ng2-select.js'}

    }
});
```